# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `VerifyAccountSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a verify API, which generates a random token and map it with user

**AttributeError at /api/verify/**

Got **AttributeError** when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `VerifyAccountSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AllVerifyOrForgotToken` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AllVerifyOrForgotToken' object has no attribute 'email'.

`models.py`

```py
class AllVerifyOrForgotToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name='User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    token = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.token)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class VerifyAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = AllVerifyOrForgotToken
        fields = ('email',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        return AllVerifyOrForgotToken.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

`viewsets.py`

```py
class VerifyViewset(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
  queryset = AllVerifyOrForgotToken.objects.all()
  serializer_class = VerifyAccountSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    email = serializer.validated_data['email']
    try:
      user = User.objects.get(email=email)
      serializer.save(
        token=token_generator(32), #function to generate random string
        user=user,
      )
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      raise APIException(detail='User does not exist')
```